# Can't init 407 or 515 drivers for Nvida Geforce GTX 650 Ti - under 20.04 or 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04

Preface -- for my application I cannot run/use the nouveau drivers, must use an actual NVIDIA driver.

Have repeatedly purged and installed and reinstalled both the 470 legacy driver and the current 515 driver. 470 driver either only provides 680x480 resolution or gives no video at all. So resorted to the current 515 driver. Note: have tried under both 20.04 and 22.04 which is currently installed.

Am running the following environment:

> HP-Pavilion KC880AA-ABA m9150f/Benicia.

> Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz

> 8192 MB/PC2-6400 memory

> Running Ubuntu 22.04

> The video card is a GeForce GTX 650 Ti

Get the following message that continually loops on boot:

> NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650 Ti GPU installed in this system supported through the NVIDIA 470.xx Legacy drivers. Please visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more information. The 515.48.07 NVIDIA driver will ignore this GPU. Continuing probe...

I can however ssh in to the system, remove the drivers, get back to the low res 470, etc.

**What can I do to fix?**

I've spent COPIOUS time with NVIDIA docs and have followed all steps completely but to no solution.

*any* help will be very much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this wizard](https://www.nvidia.com/pl-pl/geforce/drivers/) NVIDIA drivers 470.xx series seems to be the last one that supports Linux for NVIDIA 650 TI :(

I don't know about 22.04 but in Ubuntu 20.04 I am able to use the 470 drivers. I expect newer version would not work :(

(Hope this helps) I am attaching full list of my Ubuntu 20.04 nvidia/nouvae releated drivers:

```bash
marcin@pc:~$ sudo apt list --installed  |grep nvidia

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libnvidia-cfg1-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-common-470/focal-security,focal-security,focal-updates,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-extra-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-ifr1-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-ifr1-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.15.0-48-generic/focal-security,focal-updates,now 5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-security,focal-updates,now 5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-48-generic/focal-security,focal-updates,now 5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-48-generic/focal-security,focal-updates,now 5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-compute-utils-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-driver-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-kernel-common-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-source-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-prime/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 0.8.16~0.20.04.2 all [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/focal-updates,now 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-utils-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470/focal-security,focal-updates,now 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

marcin@pc:~$ sudo apt list --installed  |grep nouvea

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libdrm-nouveau2/focal-security,focal-updates,now 2.4.107-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libdrm-nouveau2/focal-security,focal-updates,now 2.4.107-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 i386 [installed,automatic]
nouveau-firmware/focal,focal,now 20091212-0ubuntu1 all [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/focal,now 1:1.0.16-1 amd64 [installed]
marcin@pc:~$
```